# If $u$ is separable over $K$ and $v$ is purely inseparble over $K$, then $K(u,v)=K(u+v)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've been having problems with this exercise of Hungerford's book, Algebra. I have been studying the section of separability by myself, and I already have a solution of the excercise, but it's very lengthy and cumbersome. I'm here looking for a better solution:

Let $F$ be a field extention of $K$, and $u\in F$ a separable element over K, $v\in F$ a purely inseparable element over $K$. Show that $K(u,v)=K(u+v)$.

My proof consist in show that $K(u+v)\subseteq K(u,v)$ and then show that $K(u,v)$ is both, separable and purely inseparable over $K(u+v)$, leading to the conclusion desired, but my method is not a very elegant one.

I would be grateful to see another solutions, thanks.

Comment: Daniel Mejia, perhaps this is common terminology but what does it mean for an *element* to be purely inseparable? That $K(v)/K$ is purely inseparable?

Comment: @AlexYoucis it means that the irreducible polynomial of $v$ has the form $f=(x-v)^{m}$ por $m\geq 0$

Comment: @AlexYoucis but in fact they are equivalent definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can suppose char$(K)=p>0$. We have $v^{p^m}=a\in K$ for some $m\geq0$, so $u^{p^m}=\bigl[(u+v)-v\bigr]^{p^m}=(u+v)^{p^m}-a\in K(u+v)\,.$ Therefore the element $u$ is purely inseparable over $K(u+v)$; but since $u$ is separable over $K$, then $u$ is also separable over $K(u+v)$. Consequently $u\in K(u+v)$, which in turn implies $v=(u+v)-u\in K(u+v)$, as desired.

Comment: Very nice !, this is a simplified version of my proof, thank you. I will post my proof later.

Comment: I want to say, that this argument applies exactly to show under the same hypothesis that $K(u,v)=K(uv)$ ($u,v\neq 0$)

Comment: @DanielMejia You are welcome, *paisano* ;-)