# $K(u, v) = K(u+v)$ when characteristic of $K=0$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, separable-extension

Let $F$ be a field extension of $K$ where $u, v$ are in $F$ such that $u$ is separable over $K$ and $v$ is purely inseparable over $K$. The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328573/if-u-is-separable-over-k-and-v-is-purely-inseparble-over-k-then-ku-v) shows that $K(u, v) = K(u+v)$ when characteristic of $K = p > 0$. Does this still hold when the characteristic of $K=0$?

Comment: Yes trivially ${}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns How is it trivial?

Comment: What's the meaning of purely inseparable?

Comment: @reuns The minimal irreducible polynomial of $v$ is $(x-v)^m$ for some $m$.

Comment: And how does $char(K)=0$ affect this?

Comment: @reuns You have to use the binomial theorem to expand $(x-v)^m$

Comment: No, you have to look at the derivative of $(x-v)^m$ which may contradict minimality if $m >1$

Comment: Extensions of fields of characteristic $0$ are always separable. So purely inseparable extensions are trivial.

Comment: For a different look, the degree $m-1$ term of $(x-v)^m$ has coefficient $-mv$ which is thus an element of $K$. When $m\cdot 1_K\neq 0_K$ this implies that $v\in K$...